# Specify multiple screen resolutions in grub

Tags: 14.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in Hyper-V, and I was able to specify the resolution in the `grub` config file by doing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1280x720"`.

But my question is, since this defines only a single resolution within the Ubuntu experience, **is there a way to specify multiple resolutions so that I can have multiple options within Ubuntu to change the screen resolution**?

If not, what's the best way to do this?  I.e. sometimes I want to run Ubuntu with 1280x720, but other times I may want to run the DE with 1024x768.

Thanks in advance!